# "Just wanted to know whether you consider reading this at all"

Tags: sentence-construction

In chat, there were these lines:

> xxx: Check %title name% out. Pretty nice work.
>   (after a couple of days)
>   xxx: So, what do you think about it?
>   yyy: Sorry, didn't have time to look at it.
>   xxx: That's ok. Just wanted to know whether you consider reading this at all.

Is the last sentence of *xxx* correct? Especially **at all** part.

Comment: Grammar or politics?

Comment: Since you are wondering, it hasn't happened yet. So I would write "Just wanted to know whether you *will/would* consider reading this at all." Use *at all* only if you want to emphasize the fact that they might not want to read it at all (for example if you asked repeatedly).

Comment: @WeatherVane, politics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the structure is correct, accept that I would add something like:
Just wanted to know whether you would consider reading this at all. -OR-
Just wanted to know whether you had considered reading this at all.

"at all" could be left off of the sentence.

Using the word "this" is OK, because the subject you are referring to (%title name%) is still in context. If the subject was not present, you would want to refer back to the subject "%title name%".